# Get all users by Organization name in People app of HTC One X

Tags: htc-one-x, people-app

I have HTC One X and I have stored my contacts in the People app. I have put Organization name  in their details. I want to view all the users belonging to a particular organization. I am unable to find a way to do that.

Is there a way to view all my contacts in People app by Organization name or at least search by it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found my answer.

In People app go to `Menu > Settings` and tap on the setting `Search contacts by`. There mark the option of `Company` as selected. There you go :)

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Go Contacts EX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jbapps.contactpro).

One of its features is `Quick find: by any letter, name, company, keyword`.

Comment: Any other option which does not require installation of third party contacts app?

Comment: @Naveen I'm not sure. Anyway, I use Samsung Galaxy S4. The stock Contacts app can't search by organization. The 3rd-party Contacts+ app can't either. However, Go Contacts Ex WORKS! :)